# In R, why does subsetting on a column with NA return a whole row of NA?

Tags: r

Subsetting on a column with NA returns a whole row of NA. I know there are multiple ways to avoid this; my question is why does this happen at all? For example:

```
> d<-data.frame(a = 1:3, b = c(NA, 2, 5))
> d[d$b == 2,]
    a  b
NA NA NA
2   2  2
```

I would understand if it simply returned row 1 also, but it returns a whole row of NA which never existed in the object I subsetted. This seems strange and unhelpful, and I can't find an explanation of **why** this behavior exists (again, I know how to prevent it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unintuitive indeed, but if you check `d$b == 2` you see that:

```r
> d$b == 2
#[1]    NA  TRUE FALSE
```

And when you subset a row with NA, it adds a NA row:

```r
> d[c(NA, 2), ]
#    a  b
#NA NA NA
#2   2  2
```

`d[d$b == 2, ]` cannot return the first row, since the first value of `d$b == 2` should be 1, and here it is `NA`.

Comment: Reducing it to d[c(NA, 2), ] as you did was helpful. So it seems like the logic is "an unknown row number could be anything, so make all its values NA". I still cannot imagine a situation in which this is useful behavior. And it seems like that logic is stretched further when there are multiple NA, because it creates multiple NA rows: d[c(NA, NA, F, T),].

Comment: It basically boils down to "how to handle equality with NAs", R, solves it with the result being NA, e.g. `NA == 2` returns `NA`. I can get this is not intuitive!

Answer (score 1):

Apart from [Maël's right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74236092/8245406), to return only the `TRUE` values, use `which`. It returns the indices *for which* the condition is `TRUE`.

```r
d <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = c(NA, 2, 5))
d[d$b == 2,]
#>     a  b
#> NA NA NA
#> 2   2  2

d[which(d$b == 2), ]
#>   a b
#> 2 2 2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>